# How to run a loop function till getting value from an API in a cypress project

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, cypress

I have to loop a function to get the value from the API in cypress project. (Multiple times, we will call the API until we get the value.

```
let otpValue = '';
const loopFunc = () => {
    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://tesurl/api/otp/getotp',
    }).then((res) => {
      expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
      res.body.OTPCode !== null ? (otpValue = res.body.OTPCode) : loopFunc();
      
    });
  };
cy.get('otpinput').type(otpValue)
```

But the loop function not working. I am expecting untill get the 'OTPCode' value not null the loop function will run.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a problem where you need to use a service worker

Comment: Its a cypress project will get the OTP code through API until get the value the loop function will run once received OTP value stop the loop

Comment: That's what you said in the question. Why repeat in comment? Better explain what *"not working"* means: what happens that is undesired?

Comment: What do you expect `? res.body.OTPCode` to do? This value is going nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

In Cypress, you need to be careful with asynchronous operations, especially when working with requests. Instead of using a recursive loop, you can use Cypress' retry mechanism combined with a custom assertion to wait for the API response with a non-null OTP code. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
let otpValue = '';

const getOtp = () => {
  return cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://testurl/api/otp/getotp',
  });
};

const waitUntilOtpNotNull = () => {
  return getOtp().then((res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);

    if (res.body.OTPCode !== null) {
      otpValue = res.body.OTPCode;
    } else {
      // Retry until OTPCode is not null
      cy.wait(1000); // Adjust the wait time as needed
      waitUntilOtpNotNull();
    }
  });
};

// Usage
waitUntilOtpNotNull().then(() => {
  // Once the OTP is obtained, type it into the input
  cy.get('otpinput').type(otpValue);
});
```